# Import normals doesn't work

Tags: python

Trying to import model to Blender 2.67 using guide:

http://wiki.xentax.com/index.php/Blender_Import_Guide#Vertex_normals

But importing normals doesn't work.

Code sample:

```
...
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(obname)
mesh.from_pydata(vlist, edges, faces)

from bpy_extras import object_utils
object_utils.object_data_add(context, mesh, operator=None)
...
vindex = 0
for vertex in mesh.vertices:
    vertex.normal = (0, 0, 1)
    vindex += 1
```

All normals must be oriented along z, but they seems to be random.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like importing normals is impossible with 2.67 version of Blender. Blender recalculates them manually.

But for version 2.74 you can import custom normals using code sample:

```
normals2 = []
for l in mesh.loops:
    normals2.append(nlist[l.vertex_index])
mesh.normals_split_custom_set(normals2)
mesh.use_auto_smooth = True
```